# Use more placeholders in WHERE statement after IN statement with arrays

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I need more placeholders to be added to the following query. Is this possible? I have no idea where to begin and I can not find any options on the Internet.

The query now:

```
$in2  = str_repeat('?,', count($arrayid) - 1) . '?';
$sql2 = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS totalacc FROM account WHERE id IN ($in2) ";
$stmt2  = $mysqli->prepare($sql2);
$types2 = str_repeat('i', count($arrayid));
$stmt2->bind_param($types2,...$arrayid);
$stmt2->execute();
$stmt2->bind_result($row['totalacc']);
    while($stmt2->fetch()) $totalacc = $row['totalacc'];
```

The query I am aiming for:

```
$countname1 = '(Hallo)';
    $countname = trim(filter_var("%{$countname1}%", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
$in2  = str_repeat('?,', count($arrayid) - 1) . '?';
$sql2 = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS totalacc FROM account WHERE id IN ($in2) AND name LIKE ?";
$stmt2  = $mysqli->prepare($sql2);
$types2 = str_repeat('i', count($arrayid));
$stmt2->bind_param($types2,s,...$arrayid,$countname); // Will never work, but how to do this? 
$stmt2->execute();
$stmt2->bind_result($row['totalacc']);
    while($stmt2->fetch()) $totalacc = $row['totalacc'];
```

Comment: If you move the `LIKE` condition to be before the `IN()` condition, this becomes easier to integrate.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski does it make any difference? I would say binding all types as string would make it much simpler

Comment: @Martin15789 any chance you can use PDO?

Comment: No, i have learned mysqli prepared a few months back. I find PDO harder to understand for some reason.

Comment: @YourCommonSense the one thing it makes easier is allowing to continue using `$...arrayid` if the string is prepended. But all the other str_repeat need modification. I agree that moving them all to string types would help too

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski `the one thing it makes easier is allowing to continue using $...arrayid if the string is prepended` ...why would that make any difference? It's an array. Doesn't matter if the countname value is at the start or the end of it. I've posted an answer below, do you have reason to believe it would fail?

Comment: @ADyson and Dharman, I tested these codes and both work. One question though, what if another AND parameter should be added, do I use the same  `$arrayid[] = $countname;` and add lets say `$arrayid[] = $countage;` ?

Comment: @ADyson In your implementation, the `$in2` string might be one ? too long if the array is appended early, making the IN() include the string. Easily fixed, but if OP says it works, it works!

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski `if the array is appended early`...if the array is appended to what? I'm not following you. In my example I clearly attached the $countname to the array after $arrayid had already been used to build $in2, if that's what you're referring to. But that isn't "appending the array" - I'm not sure what you mean by that exactly.

Comment: @ADyson I see it in there now, I overlooked your array append just before the bind, wrongly assuming it was "implied"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to use PDO instead of mysqli. This would be so much easier.

If you are stuck with mysqli then you can achieve a similar thing by simply ignoring the types and appending your result to the array.

```
$countname1 = '(Hallo)';
$countname = "%{$countname1}%";
$in2 = str_repeat('?,', count($arrayid) - 1) . '?';
$sql2 = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS totalacc FROM account WHERE id IN ($in2) AND name LIKE ?";
$stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare($sql2);

$arrayid[] = $countname;
$stmt2->bind_param(str_repeat('s', count($arrayid)), ...$arrayid);
$stmt2->execute();
$stmt2->bind_result($totalacc);
$stmt2->fetch();
```

You could even write a function to abstract from all of this code.

Comment: Is it posible to add another AND with placeholder to this line of code?

Comment: Of course, just append another item to the array.

Comment: One problem though.. When there are no results from the IN because it is based on filters. I get the following error: No data supplied for parameters in prepared.. How do I get rid of that ?

Comment: If you want to build SQL query dynamically then this is a different problem altogether. You would need to use `if` statements to construct the query and also construct an array of parameters at the same time. However, I can't show you this in comments.

Comment: I have edited my question, can you show me in the answer? Or do i need to open a new discussion for this?

Comment: @Martin15789 I would advise to roll back that edit. It changes your question significantly. As I said, this is a separate issue. You can check my earlier answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65217005/1839439

Comment: I have rolled back the edit. I have also looked at your answer. As I am not that know with that part I find it hard to get how to apply that answer to my situation, sorry. I will try to make it work else I will open a new topic.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to append the extra values to your array of parameters and string of types. This should work (untested):

```
$countname1 = '(Hallo)';
$countname = trim(filter_var("%{$countname1}%", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
$in2  = str_repeat('?,', count($arrayid) - 1) . '?';

$sql2 = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS totalacc FROM account WHERE id IN ($in2) AND name LIKE ?";
$stmt2  = $mysqli->prepare($sql2);

$types2 = str_repeat('i', count($arrayid));
$types2 .= "s"; //append "s" to the end of the $types2 string.
$arrayid[] = $countname; //append the value of $countname to the array of parameters

$stmt2->bind_param($types2, ...$arrayid); 
$stmt2->execute();
//...etc
```